# Where to store reusable content that is not a page

Tags: customization, content

I want to store content like an address block or opening times, that will be displayed at different locations across the site. The website owner should be able to edit this content. What's the best way of storing these snippets of content? I could use a page for it, or create a custom post type, but that doesn't feel right.

Comment: Custom post type is absolutely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Settings API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) to create a settings page where the admin can enter the address, opening times or whatever is needed. The same can be accomplished by using the [Customizer](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API).